# Getting a list of servers listening on a specific port in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm developing an android app which is used to remote control PC from an android phone. I managed to develop a fully functional app (client and server(java) app) except i have to specify for the client on which IP to connect. Both client and server are opening a socket and listening on port 8998. Is there a way of getting a list of servers (on client side) listening on that specific port?

Thank you in advance,

Kristian

```
    try {

        InetAddress serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(Constants.SERVER_IP); // getting the inet adress of the server
        NetworkInterface netInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(serverAddress); // getting the interface name where all other servers should be
        Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = netInterface.getInetAddresses();

        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(addresses)) {

            out.println("InetAddress: " +  inetAddress);
            Log.d("adresses", String.valueOf(inetAddress));
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("err", "Unknown hostname!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of getting a list of servers (on client side) listening on that specific port?

Iterate over all relevant IP addresses and see if you can connect on that port for each of them. It is up to you to decide your algorithm for "all relevant IP addresses", though a common one is to check all on the /24 subnet (e.g., if the device's IP address is 192.168.1.57, check all 192.168.1.* addresses except 57).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am more or less farmilliar with the way i should get the results, I really just struggle with the implementation.. I edited my question and pasted the code I'm trying with so if You could help me , I would be very thankfull. With this code my app crashes so i really don't know what to do.

Comment: @user3632600: "With this code my app crashes" -- then log the actual exception, instead of eating it, by passing your `Exception` `e` as the third parameter to `Log.e()`. Then, use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.